# Failure starting sunspot solr server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I have a problem with starting the sunspot server. last week it worked like a charm but now i get an error when i run rake sunspot:solr:run

my output using --trace

```
C:\contractbeheersysteem2>rake sunspot:solr:run --trace
** Invoke sunspot:solr:run (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:run
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b22)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode, sharing)
2012-05-14 10:10:28.077::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2012-05-14 10:10:28.374::INFO:  jetty-6.1.3
2012-05-14 10:10:28.670::INFO:  Extract jar:file:/H:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/li
b/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.1/solr/webapps/solr.war!/ to C:\DOCUME~1
\ksonnema\LOCALS~1\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_8982_solr.war__solr__-2c5peu\webapp
[Fatal Error] :107:17: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated wit
h an  element type  "name".
2012-05-14 10:10:31.577::INFO:  Started SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8982
```

hope someone knows what the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted the solr map who is located in the root directory of your app. and ran rake sunspot:solr:run again. Now a new solr map will be created in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself and the fix suggested by Kees didn't work for me. On ubuntu I simply had to upgrade my JRE and that solved the problem. Running the command `sudo apt-get install openjdk-version-here` handled the update for me.

It's also worth checking out your system monitor to make sure stale solr instances aren't already running.

Comment: glad it is solved. after i gave the answer i've got the error again, deleting the solr map did not work this time. but it is fixed now.